# Allow customer to update their customer.tag value on Shopify site

Tags: shopify

I am using the customer/register.liquid file to have customers place a value in `customers.tags` as follows:

```
<div id="customer.tags" class="clearfix large_form">
<br>label for="customer.tags" class="login">Customer Tag</label>
<br>input type="text" id="customer_tags" name="customer[tags]" id="tags" class="large"/>
<br>span class="edit-field-overlay">Customer Tag</span> </div>
```

I would like to provide a form for a customer to update their `customer.tags` field. I would like the same functionality as the customers/addresses.liquid provides for to the customer to update their address.